# which namespace does toupper belong to

Tags: c++, namespaces

when I'm reading some c++ sample code for beginner , I'm puzzled at the usage of toupper in the following line :

```
std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(), ::toupper);
```

from the above line, I know that "transform" is from namespace std , but I don't know which namespace does toupper come from . maybe there is a default namespace for c++ but
that is just my guess. so could you explain the usage of toupper here to me ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you include

```
<cctype>
```

then toupper() is in namespace std. If you include

```
<ctype.h>
```

then toupper() is in the global namespace. (The one everything ends up in if not defined in a specific namespace. The one you refer to with a leading `::` when you're in a specific namespace.)

The same rule applies to `<cstring>` vs. `<string.h>`, `<cstdlib>` vs. `<stdlib.h>` etc.

Answer (score 6):

If you are puzzled from the ::toupper syntax, it is telling you that in this case, the function is in the global namespace. You can always prepend a double colon to a name and that will tell the compiler to check in the global namespace and not search from your inner namespace out.

```
void foo() { std::cout << "global"; }
namespace inner {
   void foo() { std::cout << "inner"; }
   void call() {
      foo();   // prints inner
      ::foo(); // prints global
      ::inner::foo(); // prints inner (fully qualified namespace)
   }
}
```